# How to get the records between two different times in one day while having other day data in the same table

Tags: sql

How to get the records between two different times in one day while having other day data in the same table.

Table:

```
id reported_date         dept
1  2017-11-23 09:00:05   IT
2  2017-11-22 21:00:10   IT
3  2017-11-23 10:00:09   SC
4  2017-11-22 22:00:20   SC
5  2017-11-23 05:00:30   IT
```

The above data is captured based on below criteria: 8:00 pm (YESTERDAY)- 8:00 pm (TODAY) - WILL BE THERE IN today's table.

Now i want to flag the data if it is between 8:00 pm(previous day) - 6:00AM (today) as 'late'. as a new column or as a temp variable.

In the above table the records with 2,4,5 are to be marked as 'late', but you should not use time frame as 8-6 manually. Take the minimum time record after 8:00pm and maxtime before 6:00am.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE hour(reported_date)<6 or
      hour(reported_date)>20
```

Comment: this is not bad, could go this route in the case statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer modified and written in mysql**

```
/*SET @TODAY_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;*/ /*use this for live code*/
SET @TODAY_TIMESTAMP = '2017-11-23 14:27:10'; /*just for test scenary date of question was posed on */
SET @YesterdayEightPM = concat_ws(' ', DATE( DATE_ADD(@TODAY_TIMESTAMP, interval -1 day)),  ' 20:00:00'); 
SET @TodaySixAm  = concat_ws(' ', DATE(@TODAY_TIMESTAMP), '06:00:00');

CREATE temporary table  IF NOT EXISTS TBL_TEMP
( 
    id int,
    reported_date DATETIME,    
    dept varchar(40)
);

DELETE FROM TBL_TEMP where 1=1;

INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP (id,reported_date,dept)
VALUES (1,'2017-11-23 09:00:05', 'IT'),
       (2,'2017-11-22 21:00:10','IT'),
       (3,'2017-11-23 10:00:09','SC'),
       (4,'2017-11-22 22:00:20','SC'),
       (5,'2017-11-23 05:00:30','IT');   

SELECT ID, reported_date, dept,
       CASE WHEN reported_date BETWEEN CAST(@YesterdayEightPM AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@TodaySixAm AS DATETIME) THEN 'Late'                                       
       ELSE  'Normal' END AS 'Type',
       @TODAY_TIMESTAMP As TODAY_TIMESTAMP, 
       @YesterdayEightPM AS Yesterday8PM, 
       @TodaySixAm AS Today6AM
FROM TBL_TEMP;
```

**Original Answer written in sql server**

```
DECLARE @TODAY_TIMESTAMP DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DECLARE @YesterdayEightPM DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(DD, -1,@TODAY_TIMESTAMP) as varchar(50)) + ' 20:00:00.000'
DECLARE @TodaySixAm DATETIME = CAST(@TODAY_TIMESTAMP as varchar(50)) + ' 06:00:00.000'

SELECT @YesterdayEightPM AS Yesterday8PM, @TodaySixAm AS Today6AM

DECLARE @TBL_TEMP TABLE 
( 
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [reported_date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,    
    [dept] [varchar](40) NULL   
)

INSERT INTO @TBL_TEMP (ID, reported_date, dept)
VALUES  (1,'2017-11-23 09:00:05', 'IT'),
        (2,'2017-11-22 21:00:10','IT'),
        (3,'2017-11-23 10:00:09','SC'),
        (4,'2017-11-22 22:00:20','SC'),
        (5,'2017-11-23 05:00:30','IT')

SELECT  ID, reported_date, dept,
        CASE WHEN TT.reported_date BETWEEN     @YesterdayEightPM AND @TodaySixAm THEN 'Late'
        ELSE 'Normal'END
FROM @TBL_TEMP TT   WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: what is the database is this? can you give me in mysql way please or a simple sql?

Comment: this was written in sql server. will write it in mysql for you quickly and post another answer

Comment: Hi @sindhuY , i have now added mysql if you view my answer. hope this helps.